# Expo Refresh only working in certain components

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

so I am just digging into building apps with React Native/Expo and I have come across a weird behavior that I am not sure why is happening. I have a dashboard component that returns a 'UsersFlatList' component

```
      const DashBoard = () => {
                    return (
                                  <>
          <View style={styles.dashboard__wrapper}>
            <TextInput
              placeholder="why is this working??
            "
              style={styles.form__input}
            ></TextInput>
            <UsersFlatList />
          </View>
        </>
      )
    }
```

If I change that text - I see the changes happening in expo go immediately. However if I make changes to the data in the flatlist, I don't see any changes at all and I have to refresh the app to see any of the updates changes.

```
    import { useEffect, useState } from "react"
    import { Text, View, SafeAreaView, FlatList, StyleSheet } from "react-native"
    import UserCard from "./UserCard"
    import { collection, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore"
    import db from "../firebaseConfig"
    
    const UsersFlatList = () => {
      const [onlineUsers, setOnlineUsers] = useState([])
    
      useEffect(() => {
        const fetchAllData = async () => {
          const foundUsers = await getDocs(collection(db, "users"))
          const currentUsers = []
          foundUsers.forEach((user) => currentUsers.push(user.data()))
    
          setOnlineUsers(() => currentUsers)
        }
    
        const matchedUsers = fetchAllData()
      }, [])
    
     
      return (
        <FlatList
          data={onlineUsers}
          renderItem={UserCard}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.email}
        ></FlatList>
      )
    }
    
    export default UsersFlatList
```

```
    import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from "react-native"
    
    const UserCard = ({ item }) => {
      console.log(item)
      return (
        <View style={styles.userCard}>
          <View style={styles.online__icon}></View>
          <Text>{item.username} is a</Text>
        </View>
      )
    }
    
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({})
    
    export default UserCard
```

Appreciate this is a long one to read but any help or a pointer would be amazing thanks

Comment: How are you making changes to the flat list?

Comment: I am just changing the text inside the <Text> component inside userCard

Comment: But you said "However if I make changes to the data in the flatlist, I don't see any changes at all and I have to refresh the app to see any of the updates changes." - so how is the data in the flat list changing?

Comment: The Flatlist renders to the UserCard. If I change any data in the UserCard I don't see any difference to what the FlatList renders. It just always looks the same

Comment: But how are you changing the data? Your TextInput does nothing (according to your code) to change the data. The flatlist is a list of user cards, which are populated from the DB in useEffect which is only run on load.